# How to reduce the size of a ggplot figure? The plot has too many lines and thus weights too much

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting the results of a simulations study, where I have repeated for 500 times a certain analysis. I would like to show how a quantity changes over time across simulations (spaghetti plot) to show the heterogeneity in the simulations. However there are too many lines and the plot gets to heavy (using ggssave in pdf). Any suggestions how to get a lighter picture without loosing too much resolution?

Below an example of code and picture

```r
ggplot(sim_data, aes(month, val, group = sim)) +
  geom_line(col = "grey") +
  facet_wrap(upper_cap_letter ~ lower_cap_letter)
```

[image: example picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a rasterisation function that I [posted on github](https://gist.github.com/teunbrand/c3f5d2d1a8e94294ddeed1d2f22687d2) that could help reduce the file size. It'll take a bit longer to render the figure but the filesize will probably be smaller.

You can control how munch resolution you want by setting `dpi` appropriately.

```r
# Script gives the rasterise function
source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/teunbrand/c3f5d2d1a8e94294ddeed1d2f22687d2/raw/6ebe4c2f801191fc1195ee8d28dccb97373db14c/rasterising_ggplot_layers.R")
#> Warning: package 'ragg' was built under R version 4.0.2

# 125000 observations
df <- expand.grid(1:50, LETTERS[1:5], letters[1:5], 1:100)
df$y <- runif(nrow(df))


ggplot(df, aes(Var1, y, group = Var4)) +
  rasterise(geom_line(), dpi = 300) +
  facet_wrap(~ Var2 + Var3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note: I wrote the function to [add into the ggraster](https://github.com/VPetukhov/ggrastr/pull/17) package, so if you're seeing this post a while from now, it is probably there.